# Array ( [0] => 'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [1] => operable program or batch file. ) in php

Tags: php, command-line, command

I want to execute the following command

```
exec("c:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI -i D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/output.flv -e x264 -a 1 -E faac -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0.0 -f mp4 -I -m -x level=30:bframes=0:weightp=0:cabac=0:ref=1:vbv-maxrate=768:vbv-bufsize=2000:analyse=all:me=umh:no-fast-pskip=1:subme=6:8x8dct=0:trellis=0 -b 250 -B 64 -R 48 -X 480 -w 480 -l 320 -2 -o D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/w2.mp4 2>&1",$output);
```

in php but after executing i am gettting the following error message:

> Array ( [0] => 'c:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, [1] => operable program or batch file. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a space in the path. You will have to put the path between `"`

Like so:

```
exec("\"c:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI\" -i D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/output.flv -e x264 -a 1 -E faac -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0.0 -f mp4 -I -m -x level=30:bframes=0:weightp=0:cabac=0:ref=1:vbv-maxrate=768:vbv-bufsize=2000:analyse=all:me=umh:no-fast-pskip=1:subme=6:8x8dct=0:trellis=0 -b 250 -B 64 -R 48 -X 480 -w 480 -l 320 -2 -o D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/w2.mp4 2>&1",$output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the space in the file name between 'Program' and 'Files'

Since I don't know which language 'exec' is from I can't offer the exact solution, but if i were you I'd try adding quotes around

```
c:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI
```

so maybe

```
exec("'c:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI' -i D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/output.flv -e x264 -a 1 -E faac -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0.0 -f mp4 -I -m -x level=30:bframes=0:weightp=0:cabac=0:ref=1:vbv-maxrate=768:vbv-bufsize=2000:analyse=all:me=umh:no-fast-pskip=1:subme=6:8x8dct=0:trellis=0 -b 250 -B 64 -R 48 -X 480 -w 480 -l 320 -2 -o D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/w2.mp4 2>&1",$output);
```

Comment: stormcloud i am using php

Answer (score 0):

The path "Program Files" contains a space so you need to wrap it around with single quotes `'`

> c:\Program Files

Eg:

```
exec('"c:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI -i D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/output.flv -e x264 -a 1 -E faac -6 dpl2 -R Auto -D 0.0 -f mp4 -I -m -x level=30:bframes=0:weightp=0:cabac=0:ref=1:vbv-maxrate=768:vbv-bufsize=2000:analyse=all:me=umh:no-fast-pskip=1:subme=6:8x8dct=0:trellis=0 -b 250 -B 64 -R 48 -X 480 -w 480 -l 320 -2 -o D:/wamp/www/upload_google_drive/w2.mp4 2>&1"',$output);
```